# Does a cat that lost an eye from infection need to have its eye sewn shut?

Tags: cats, veterinarian, eye-disease

For the past few weeks, a stray kitten has been wandering to my house and getting more and more comfortable staying around. When he came, he has an eye infection, and now he has lost his entire left eye. I did some googling and found that cats who lost their eye usually get their eye sewn shut to prevent further infection, and since this kitten now practically lives on my house, I decided to bring him to a vet. The vet however said that the eye socket seems to be fine on its own and only needs to be cleaned with eye drops every once in a while. Is it true that a cat that has lost its eye may not need to have its eye sewn shut?

Comment: **Note to close-voters**: The cat in question has received veterinary care and OP is not asking for any advice to replace veterinary care. They are asking for a second oppinion whether or not additional procedures are common or needed.

Comment: It is preferable, yes.

Comment: Sewing the eye socket shut is generally a long-term precaution to prevent further complication. If nothing can get in there, nothing can cause problems in there. Additionally, while the cat will not care a whole lot about the aesthetics, we humans do and as such the procedure may also be beneficial for human-cat-interaction, i.e. humans might approach a cat with an eye sewn shut differently than one that has a gaping hole where an eye should be.